# Getting errors while loading a browersify coverted npm package and using it in a script tag?

Tags: node.js, express, browserify, cdn

I am using a npm module called lottie-web which basically gives you a svg animation ,if you give it a json data file which i get from the adobe after effects(to keep things short all it does is takes a html element by its id and in the path it takes a json data file and loads the svg in the given element).I am using a node application with express and using handlebars(hbs) to render the frontend to the browser, So in this case we need to attach  a script tag of the lottie-web cdn link or the other way is we can use browserify to convert the given file below  and run **browserify myfilename -o bundle.js** command and then use the bundle.js in the script tag to load the js in the client side

```js
const bodymovin = require('bodymovin')

var animation = bodymovin.loadAnimation({
  container: document.getElementById('loader'),
  renderer: 'svg',
  loop: true,
  autoplay: true,
  path: '../../public/js/loader.json'
})
```

If i go with the first approach (i.e using a cdn link) i am getting a the following error  **lottie.js:4406 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'responseText' property from 'XMLHttpRequest': The value is only accessible if the object's 'responseType' is '' or 'text' (was 'json').
at formatResponse (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bodymovin/5.6.10/lottie.js:4406:17)
at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bodymovin/5.6.10/lottie.js:4424:26)**

and if i go with the second approach (i.e using a browserify bundled js file) i am getting the following error  **VM2609:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
at JSON.parse ()
at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (bundle.js:8583)**

but if i try it using a cdn link in a normal html file and adding a js file to run the code given above (i.e outside my folder structure in a normal html css js structure it works fine).
Can someone point me out where i am going wrong,thanks in advance.

Comment: You can clone the git repo given below to check the actual code    [link](https://github.com/tarunjamana/weather-website/tree/browserify)

Comment: the files which  are dependent to this question are  1.  loader.js(client side js file )  loader.json(the json file which gives you the animation)  bundle.js(which is the bundle from browserify)  in the public/js folder  2.lottie.js(the js file which is bundled by browserify ) in the  src/utils folder 3. forecast.hbs(the handlebar which is using the script tags) and loader.hbs(which contains the element where  animation is to be rendered ) in the templates/views and template/partials files respectively . Hope this info helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those errors make me think that your webservers answer is incorrect, when the underlying asset (`../../public/js/loader.json`) is loaded with the XMLHttpRequest.

Try opening up the browsers console and check the `Network` tab, see whats happening for that request. The `Response` should be a proper JSON. Also check the `Headers` of that request, you might notice something there too.

After checking out your git repo, the thing I've noticed, that you have an express route: `app.get('*' ,(req,res) => {`, that answers w/ an HTM text generated by `404.hbs`.

I think when you want to load that `JSON` this rule gets executed, which then renders HTML back for the caller, which raises the error you see.

Another weird thing is that I don't see those lines `bodymovin.loadAnimation` in your git repo...

### Update 1:

[This line](https://github.com/tarunjamana/weather-website/blob/browserify/public/js/bundle.js#L14363) should be `path: './js/loader.json'` since you are serving the `public` directory w/ express as asset root, and your `json` file lives under `public/js/loader.json`.

Also after fixing that another issue popped up, probably your `JSON` is misconfigured, but I'm not gonna fix that also for u. Take care.

Comment: yes upon checking the network tab i  see my  loader.json containing the 404page, how to fix this issue

Comment: @JamanaTarun so fix that by having correct routes / files for your `public` folder, and it should start to work properly.

Comment: @JamanaTarun ok, push code to github where this `bodymovin.loadAnimation` call is present. On the current link I can't find it where you call it in your code.

Comment: you can check it in the browserify branch of the repo  , the bodymovin.loadanimation call is present in src/utils/lottie.js and even in public/js/loader.js